# Register to consul cluster - how to sync node or handle multi node connection

Tags: java, openshift, consul

We have a consul cluster containing 3 nodes on Openshift, a single route that forwards HTTP requests to a random node.
Our problem is that when we try to register a service or send a heartbeat the request gets forwarded to a single node therefore there is a chance that a heartbeat will arrive at a node that the service was not registered in.

So my question is are we doing something very wrong with the way we are using consul or there is any configuration used to sync between the nodes?

Other information: we are using java with the org.orbitz consul client

Answer (score 0):

In addition to operating 3 Consul servers, Consul's Helm chart should also configure Consul client agents to run as a daemonset across all other K8s workers in your cluster (see [Consul on Kubernetes: Architecture](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/installation/install#architecture)).

You can then configure your application to register itself against the Consul client agent which is running on the same node. [See Accessing the Consul HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/installation/install#accessing-the-consul-http-api) for info on obtaining the IP for the client agent.

However, this service registration method is uncommon on Kubernetes. An easier route would be to enable Consul's K8s [service catalog sync](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/service-sync) if you're using Consul purely for service discovery. If you are using it for service mesh, the service registration process will be automatically handled when the proxy (and associated containers) is injected alongside your application.